# R gbm categorical variables error

Tags: r, levels, gbm

I am trying to create a model using gbm in R but I am getting an error.

```
train=read.csv("~/Downloads/train-3.csv", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
test=read.csv("~/Downloads/test-3.csv")
head(train)
randomSeed = 1738
set.seed(randomSeed)
library(gbm)

LogLossBinary = function(actual, predicted, eps = 1e-15) {  
  predicted = pmin(pmax(predicted, eps), 1-eps)  
  - (sum(actual * log(predicted) + (1 - actual) * log(1 - predicted))) / length(actual)
}
gbmModel = gbm(formula = Retweet_count ~ Text + Time,
           distribution = "bernoulli",
           data = train2,
           n.trees = 2500,
           shrinkage = .01,
           n.minobsinnode = 20)
```

The error is this

```
Error in gbm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, distribution = distribution, w = w,  : 
gbm does not currently handle categorical variables with more than 1024 levels. Variable 1: 
Text has 2000 levels.
```

What are the levels and what would be a way to fix this and still be able to use the gbm?

Comment: You didn't add some example.. but according to the error you get, _text_ variable has to many levels. Each categorical variable has levels.. for example, I can have _gender_ variable with two levels: Man or Women. In order to solve this problem you should remove some levels or group some of them in a different way.

Comment: In R 'levels' are unique text value attributes for 'factor' variables.

Comment: @staove7 so I am trying to find out how many retweets a tweet will get and have 2000 unique tweets. Is there a way to make it have less levels?

Comment: Id Text         Time Retweet_count                                                                   1 rt chairmannhrc: national #humanrights commission to release pre-election rpt &amp; advisory on violence in #nigeria2015 friday, 13 feb. in abâ€¦     2/12/15 16:44 7